# Working with multiple key press events (windows key)

Tags: javascript, jquery

While working with the multiple keypress events i found this code which worke fine

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {
    if( event.which === 65 && event.shiftKey ) {
        alert('you pressed SHIFT+A');
    }
});
```

But to make it to work wth combinig with windows key... like

```
event.which === 65 && event.windowsKey
```

it failed...

Is there any option to make it work with windows key?

if it is a mac machine there is no key as windows..so what could be the alternate option for windows key in mac

Comment: It doesn't act like a modifier key (like `alt` or `shift`) - it has a specific `which` value - 91 for the left Windows key, 92 for the right Windows key

Comment: @Ian, metaKey works for me in an onkeypress in **Chrome** for F, W and Y but Windows intercepts the other letters. The keys for backquote (left of "1"), backslash, period and dash are also **not** intercepted (are processed by the onkeypress). metaKey is false for those keys in **Edge and IE**. I now realize that it is futile to attempt to use the Windows key in JavaScript in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `keyup` event.
2. On a Mac left Command is `which = 91`, right Command is `which = 93`. I can't tell what are those on Windows, but you can test it yourself. *As @ian commented they should be 91 and 92 respectively.*

To test

```js
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {

    var modKey = "";
    if (e.shiftKey) modKey += "shiftKey,";
    if (e.ctrlKey)  modKey += "ctrlKey,";
    if (e.altKey)   modKey += "altKey,";
    if (e.metaKey)  modKey += "metaKey,";

    console.log ("which: " + e.which + " modkey: " + modKey );
});
```

**UPDATE:** Try use `keydown` event and `event.metaKey`

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which === 65 && event.metaKey ) {
        console.log ("You pressed Windows + A");
    }
});
```

Comment: sir, i am asking about how to recognise if a user press "windows key" on keyboard with another key..?
LIKE
window+s
windows+a

Answer (score 0):

Remember the key you pressed before. Like if you press shift. get a boolean or something to `shiftPressed = true` on a onKeyRelease make it false again. That way you can check if `shiftPressed == true && aPressed == true` before doing something

I made something a while ago for a little WASD game. Perhaps it makes more sense if you see the code:

```
var up = false;
var down = false;
var left = false;
var right = false;
function keyUp(e) {
    keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

    if (keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 65) {
        left = false;
    }

    if (keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 87) {
        up = false;
    }

    if (keyCode == 39 || keyCode == 68) {
        right = false;
    }

    if (keyCode == 40 || keyCode == 83) {
        down = false;
    }

}

function forceStopMoving() {
    left = false;
    up = false;
    right = false;
    down = false;
}


function keyDown(e) {
    keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 65) {
        left = true;
    }

    if (keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 87) {
        up = true;
    }

    if (keyCode == 39 || keyCode == 68) {
        right = true;
    }

    if (keyCode == 40 || keyCode == 83) {
        down = true;
    }
}
```